# CSS only menu for AMP site

Tags: css, amp-html

I am in process of building an AMP HTML mobile template with a CSS only menu. It has to be CSS only as the AMP HTML standards do not allow any javascript. I am sure this will help others in building an AMP HTML page with a nice menu.

I have a very basic version coded. But for some reason the menu is not appearing when I cleaned the code to be AMP. I know this is probably super simple but it is completely evading me. I put a super shortened version of my page below any help would be appreciated.

For quick reference the only errors the code below will throw from the AMP HTML debugger is the fact that I have multiple style tags, I know that is the case, I am just using them for organization purposes before combining them once in my platform.

Thanks for any help!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<link rel="canonical" href="">
<!-- AMP Requirements Begin -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style>body {opacity: 0}</style><noscript><style>body {opacity: 1}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<!-- AMP Requirements End -->
<!-- Main Style Begin -->
<style>
body {
 margin: 0px; 
}
#main-container {
 border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
 width: 100%;
}
#header-wrapper {
 border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
 width: 100%;
}
#header-wrapper span {
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
}
#header-wrapper span a {
 display: block;
}
/* Nav Bar Begin */
#navbar-container ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
#navbar-container ul li {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 display: inline;
}
/* Nav Bar End */
</style>
<!-- Main Style End -->
<!-- Menu CSS Begin -->
<style>
#main-navigation {
  
  /* Collapsed */
  width: 0; 

  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #12E444;
  &:after {
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 34px;  
  }
}

#main-container {
  float: right;
}
#main-navigation:target + #main-container {
 width: 80%;
 #main-container {
  width: 80%;
  left: 20%; 
 }
 #header-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  left: 20%;
}
</style>
<!-- Menu CSS End -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Mobile Nav Chunk Begin -->
<nav id="main-navigation">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Close Menu</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu item Long Maybe Long</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- Mobile Nav Chunk End -->
<!-- Main Wrapper Begin -->
<div id="main-container">
  <!-- Header Wrapper Begin -->
  <div id="header-wrapper">
   <span>Call US <a href="tel:303-999-9999">303-999-9999</a></span>
   <amp-img src="test-images/mobile-logo.jpg" width="142" height="51" alt=""></amp-img>
  </div>
  <!-- Header Wrapper End -->
  <!-- Nav Bar Begin -->
  <div id="navbar-container">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#main-navigation">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Nav Bar End -->
  <!-- Main Content Area Begin -->
  <div id="main-content-area">

    </div>
  <!-- Main Content Area End -->
</div>
<!-- Main Wrapper End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: width: 0; ??? Of course you will not see it...?

Comment: That is in the collapsed state. It triggers a new width on the :target. So that is why it is at 0px at that point. I tested that as well and it shows the nav at all times if you increase the width when it is collapsed.

Comment: Take a look at an example like this: https://www.washingtonpost.com/amphtml/politics/fall-of-the-house-of-bush-how-last-name-and-donald-trump-doomed-jeb/2016/02/21/bc96cc62-d8d1-11e5-925f-1d10062cc82d_story.html

Comment: Perfect example. Thank you. I will take a look at their code and build something using the lesson and share it once it is complete.

Comment: Btw they are looking to add a custom component for this so keep an eye on this thread: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/827. Until then not really seen any decent implementation this until that washingtonpost one which seems to work well! Might need to have a dig myself at that...

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-navigation:target + #main-container {
    width: 80%;
    #main-container {
        width: 80%;
        left: 20%;  
    }
    #header-wrapper {
        width: 80%;
        left: 20%;
    }                      /* <- MISSING THIS RIGHT CURLY BRACE */
}
</style>
```

Comment: full disclosure: I too was coding an AMP CSS navbar and encountered similar, hair-losing issues... turns out I had typed a parenthsis `)` instead of a curly brace `}` - and btw, the custom sidebar component thread @BazzaDP mentioned is now completed as of about a month ago; so should be good to go!